# how to assign column names available in csv file as header to orc file

Tags: scala, csv, dataframe, header

I have column names in one .csv file and want to assign these as column headers to Data Frame in scala. Since it is generic script, I don't want to hard code in the script rather pass the values from csv file.

Comment: My csv file has records as fname, lname,phone   
and data in dataframe is 

john smith 1234567
justin bieber 797800
stokes kassis 87697080

I want assign header available in csv file to this dataframe data

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

```
val columns = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("path_to_csv").schema.fieldNames
val df: DataFrame = ???
df.toDF(columns:_*).write.format("orc").save("your_orc_dir")
```

in pyspark:

```
columns = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("path_to_csv").columns
df.toDF(columns).write.format("orc").save("your_orc_dir")
```

but store data schema separately from data is bad idea

Comment: How to do the same in python?